# ring buffer on msp430

Tags: audio, buffer, uart, msp430

I´m trying to get digital data from ADC converter, using DMA module to tranfer these converted data to UART. In particular ADC send data to channel 0 of DMA(DMA0) that triggers DMA1 to send data through UART.Even if DMA in Continuous mode could allow me to get a continuous communication.  I need to do other operations while sending these data (such as send through UART samples from other Sensors) and I would like to avoid mutex while reciving sample data at the data destination.

Is DMA double buffers useful for this??

My audio signal is 8bit res 1 channel and I read on the datasheet that the maximum BITCLK clock frequency(equals baud rate in MBaud)    is 1    MHz which is the maximum SMCLK frequency that I would be able to use?

May I have an higher baud rate than 115 200 and 11 050Hz sample frequency?

How is possible to implement a ring buffer on MSP430? I need to define head and tail but I´m not able to work using poiters on MSP430
Thank you for your help!

Comment: The description of the data sent out the UART is poorly specified.  If you expect to send both ADC data and *"samples from other Sensors"*, then without a message protocol, the receiver of this data stream will have a problem identifying the data.  IOW forget about connecting the ADC DMA channel directly to another channel for immediate output by the UART.

Comment: > How is possible to implement a ring buffer on MSP430? I need to define head and tail **but I´m not able to work using poiters on MSP430** - why not?

Comment: @ sawdust I would like to define also a message protocol (such as: every x samples get a sample from the other sensor, maybe using Simulink) do you think that it will be difficoult?? I did´t understand what you were trying to sai with "IOW".

Comment: @SigveKolbeinson I´m trying to do that but I´m learning right now to use the MSP430 so it seems quite difficoult for me to face this problem of data transfer and ring buffer!
That´s why I´m searching help on this forum :)